# Laravel Artisan executed with CRON JOB does not execute Fire Command

Tags: php, laravel, cron

The path give to the CRON JOB:

```
php -q /path/to/the/artisan.php <command:name>;
```

Command works OK in Local, but when is executed through CRON JOB a `fire` method does not get executed which is placed quite near the end of script.

Artisan is full executed but FIRE is not run at all. What could be the problem?

It's also worth mentioning that it works OK with SSH but with CRON alone it does not work completely...

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell it execute it this way:

```
* * * * * /full/path/of/your/php -q /path/to/the/artisan.php <command:name>
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you need the full path?

Comment: How do we find the `/path/to/the/artisan.php` ?